# How to make PanResponder work as expected when user double taps by inadvertance while dragging his finger?

Tags: react-native, user-interface

I'm trying to build a recording button where the user needs to keep pressing on the button to record, and then release the button when he wants to finish recording. Also, if the user releases its finger while outside of the button area, the recording gets cancelled.

I'm using a PanResponder to implement this behavior:

```
<View {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
   <Button />
</View>
```

Everything works fine in the most cases. However, if the user taps somewhere else on the screen with another finger while recording (most often by inadvertance), then the PanResponder stops to capture the recording drag. The onResponderRelease method is not called.

I have no clue how to solve this. I want the recording drag to be resilient to extra touches.

I have tried catching and blocking any extra touch, if in recording state, inside the parent view but it does not work.

Any help is appreciated !